# SQL Loop Count of people in program during specified duration

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm not sure if there should be a loop for this or what the easiest approach would be.

My data consists of a list of people participating in our program. They have various start and end dates, but the following equation is able to capture the number of people who participated on a specific date:

```
DECLARE @PopulationDate DATETIME = '2018-06-01 05:00:00';
select count(People) 
FROM Program_Log
WHERE 
START_TIME <= @PopulationDate
AND (END_TIME >= @PopulationDate OR END_TIME IS NULL)`
```

Is there a way I can loop in different date values to get the number of program participants each day for an entire year? 
Multiple years?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way is to use a CTE to generate the dates and then a `left join` to bring in the data.  For instance, the following gets the counts as of the first of the month for this year:

```
with dates as (
      select cast('2018-01-01' as date) as dte
      union all
      select dateadd(month, 1, dte)
      from dates
      where dte < getdate()
     )
select d.dte, count(pl.people)
from dates d left join
     program_log pl
     on pl.start_time <= d.dte and (pl.end_time >= d.dte or pl.end_time is null)
group by d.dte
order by d.dte;
```

Note that this will work best for a handful of dates.  If you want more than 100, you need to add `option (maxrecursion 0)` to the end of the query.

Also, `count(people)` is highly suspicious.  Perhaps you mean `sum(people)` or something similar.

Comment: dateadd(day) instead of month, no?